# Okta validate login on app redirect

Tags: okta, okta-api

We have a spa (Angular 2) that we are trying to integrate with okta.  I created an app in okta with SWA sign on method.  I click on the app and it redirects me to my spa app as expected.

However, I do not see and information being passed on the redirect.  How do I validate that the login was successful? Is there some token info that I can validate?  Something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The SWA sign on method depends on the Okta plugin - do you have it installed? If so, when you hit your login page (and the origin matches the url you've configured in the app), the plugin will try to inject the creds into the login form. It uses a heuristic to figure out which fields to inject into, so ideally your login page will look like a standard login form (i.e. text field for username, password field for password, and a login button).

There are other template apps you can use if you don't want to depend on the plugin being installed (not sure about your setup) - for example, "Template App" will post the credentials to an endpoint (although this is usually not an option since most apps will want to add an XSRF token to their login forms).